# C++ Unexpected Result with std::ofstream to binary file

Tags: c++

Now I am creating the data, but I got an unexpected result.

Here is the code what I've wrote.

```
float f = 1.7005484e-09;
uchar b[4];
memcpy(&b, (unsigned char *)&f, 4);
std::ofstream fout("abc.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
fout.write((const char *)&b, sizeof(float));
fout.close();
printf("%x%x %x%x\n", b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]);
```

expected result of the File is "bab8 e930", but I got "º¸é0".

When I replace the `fout.write((const char *)&b, sizeof(float));` to

```
fout.write((const char *)&b, sizeof(float)+1);
```

I get the 'bab8 e930 00'.

What is the problem here and how to solve this problem??

Comment: `uchar b[4];` -- There is no guarantee that `float` is 4 bytes.  You use `4` in some places, `sizeof(float)` in other places.  It's either all `4` or `sizeof(float)`.  Pick one and stick to using it.

Comment: your `printf` does not concern the result after you read in the generated file (and in fact you do not read it), so what are you speaking about ? `I got "º¸é0"` is it impossible to have that result using %x in `printf`format

Comment: You confuse to print characters and to print their (ASCII) code in hexa (the code ASCII code in hexa of '0' is 30 ending your sequence)

Comment: Assuming that `sizeof(float)` is 4 and `sizeof(uchar)` is 1, `fout.write((const char *)&b, sizeof(float)+1);` will have it read out-of-bounds unless you also replaced `uchar b[4];`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several undefined behaviors in your code.

> ```
> uchar b[4];
> ```

you suppose for your compiler a `float`is sized 4, do

```
uchar b[sizeof(float)];
```

> ```
> memcpy(&b, (unsigned char *)&f, 4);
> ```

first you wanted `memcpy(b, ...`, second again you suppose the size of a `float` is 4, third you are dependent on the endianess

> ```
> fout.write((const char *)&b, sizeof(float));
> ```

first you wanted `fout.write((const char *)b, ...`, second you suppose the size of *b* is `sizeof(float)`

> ```
> printf("%x%x %x%x\n", b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]);
> ```

you suppose *b* was fully set by *memcpy* so for your compiler a `float`is sized at least 4

> expected result of the File is "bab8 e930", but I got "º¸é0".

you probably speak about the content of the generated file looking at it as it is (using *cat* for instance), out of the previous remarks the expected result can be `º¸é0` but not `"bab8 e930"` with is certainly the output produced by `printf("%x%x %x%x\n", b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]);`.

You confuse to print a character and to print its code in hexa, for instance `printf("%c", '0')` (or `putchar('0')`) produces `0` but in case your compiler use ASCII code `printf("%x", '0')` produces `30`.

> ```
>  fout.write((const char *)&b, sizeof(float)+1);
> ```

if the size of a `float` is 4 that means you write a character taken after *b*, which is again an undefined behavior